# Have little problem actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Last problem in my project.

my action mailer

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def newgrants_notification(respondent)
     recipients     respondent.email
     from           "admiN@admin.com"
     subject        "Do it"
     body        (:user => user.name, :url_base => pass_this) #i think problem is this in url?
  end
end
```

inquiry_model

```
  def pass_this
    return "http://localhost:3000/asnwer/index?user_id=#{self.id.to_i}&token=#{self.security_token}"
  end
```

in mailer_view

```
<p>Link to pass: <%= "#{@url_base}" %></p>
```

How to implement asnwer_form link from model to action_mailer::base? Now link is empty ;[
I need when i open my email: there was link to my path with right user_id and token

p.s - `security_token` in `questions` table
`user_id` in `users` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the instance of inquiry into notifier model. And access it like this !

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def newgrants_notification(respondent,inquiry_instance)
     recipients     respondent.email
     from           "admiN@admin.com"
     subject        "Do it"
     body        (:user => user.name, :url_base => inquiry_instance.pass_this) #i think problem is this in url?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response, but now i have error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)): something in question_controller ...       respondents.each do |r|
        Inquiry.create(:question_id => @question.id, :respondent_id => r.id)
        Notifier.deliver_newgrants_notification(r) 
      end

Comment: Try this ! respondents.each do |r| @inquiry = Inquiry.create(:question_id => @question.id, :respondent_id => r.id) Notifier.deliver_newgrants_notification(r,@inquiry) end

Comment: wrote. It is strange, now i got this: NoMethodError (undefined method `pass_this' for nil:NilClass): , i dont know why, hmm, i hate this problems;/

Comment: Because you are passing nil @inquiry instance. You need to check you are getting value inside @inquiry instance or not. Inquiry instance is created properly or not.